# getText() and setText() not working in android code

Tags: android, gettext, settext

hello i'm creating an android application that fills up a form and send the details to the php script on the server side in form of a string . But the problem is that i'm not able to extract or put up any new value of EditText fields. Please help..
My code is somewhat like this..

```
EditText id_st1_event_edit,id_st1_date_edit,id_st1_time_edit,id_st1_venue_edit;
EditText id_st2_name_edit,id_st2_phone_edit,id_st2_phone_edit2,id_st2_email_edit,id_st2_email_edit2;
EditText id_st3_desc_edit;

//Declaration of static IP Address of the server side 
public static String addr = "10.0.2.2";
public String sendsentence;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Attaching the entities with their proper ID Components
    welcome=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_message);
    create_event=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_create_event);
    browse_event=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_browse_event);
    about_us=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_about_us);

    id_st1_time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_time);
    id_st1_venue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_venue);
    id_st1_event=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_event);
    id_st1_date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_date);
    id_st1_next=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_next);

    id_st2_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_name);
    id_st2_phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_phone);
    id_st2_email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_email);
    about_organiser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.about_organiser);

    id_st3_event_description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_st3_event_description);

    id_st1_time_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_time_edit);
    id_st1_date_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_date_edit);
    id_st1_event_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_event_edit);
    id_st1_venue_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_venue_edit);

    id_st2_name_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_name_edit);
    id_st2_phone_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_phone_edit);
    id_st2_phone_edit2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_phone_edit2);
    id_st2_email_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_email_edit);
    id_st2_email_edit2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st2_email_edit2);

    id_st3_desc_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st3_desc_edit);

    butt_submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butt_submit);

}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Exiting Application ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void createNew(View V)
{

    setContentView(R.layout.create_new_event);
    tabhost= (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setup();        
     TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        spec=tabhost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Step 1");
        tabhost.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabhost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("Step 2");
        tabhost.addTab(spec);

        spec=tabhost.newTabSpec("tag3");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("Step 3");
        tabhost.addTab(spec);
}

public void aboutUs(View V)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
}

public void browseEvent(View V)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.browse_new);
}

public void to_next(View v)
{
    tabhost= (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setCurrentTab((tabhost.getCurrentTab())+1);

}

public void to_previous(View v)
{
    tabhost= (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setCurrentTab((tabhost.getCurrentTab())-1);     
}

public void submit_data(View V)
{
    try{
        new DoSocketProgramming(this).execute("10.0.2.2");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "created till here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class DoSocketProgramming extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String sendsentence="create table ";
    String recvsentence;
    Context context;

    //sendsentence=id_st1_event_edit.getText().toString();
    private DoSocketProgramming(Context context){
        this.context = context; 
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {   
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is preExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{            
            Socket con=new Socket(addr,1678);
            DataInputStream dis= new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeUTF(sendsentence);
            recvsentence=dis.readUTF();

        }catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Log.d("myApp","i've reached at doinbackground");
        return recvsentence;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
            Log.d("myApp","i've reached on PostExecute");
            Toast.makeText(context, "this is post execute "+ result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}}
```

the "sendsentence" in DoSocketProgramming class is shown properly at php side in the above but as soon as I try to append some Text to it using GetText() or SetText() functions, my application crashes.
what should I do ??

Comment: Do a null check on the edittext widget before you try to append the text. Is it saying it's null?

Comment: you should post your logcat here. and also I can not see use of setText method in this code. where are you trying to use setText??

Comment: @Setu Assuming you downvoted him, don't you feel bad downvoting some one with only 3 rep?

Comment: Agreed, it's a perfectly legitimate question. I would check for nulls as Clay suggested and please let us know!

Comment: I can't see any attempt to use getText() or setText() in that code.

Comment: @Squonk Use ctrl + f, it's there but it's commented so it's hard to find.

Comment: @Clay: ROFL mate. What made you assume I down voted. I made legitimate request of posting logcat. what's wrong with that? and if you could find setText() in code point me to it as well. FYI: I know how to use ctrl + f

Comment: @Setu I said "Assuming you downvoted him", if you didn't then ignore what I said. And I was talking to Squonk about that ctrl+f. Also, there is not setText() in the question, only getText().

Comment: @setu : i've removed the settext() in the code because its working nowhere in the code. Also i've commented getText() for the same reason. the code i've given is a working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't really have much to go on but I'll give it a shot.

The only line which shows using `getText()` is this one...

```
//sendsentence=id_st1_event_edit.getText().toString();
```

As mentioned in comments on the question the most likely cause is `NullPointerException`. If that's the case then `id_st1_event_edit` is null.

If that's the case then the following line in `onCreate(...)`

```
id_st1_date_edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_st1_date_edit);
```

...is failing to find an `EditText` with resource id `R.id.id_st1_date_edit` which suggests that particular `EditText` isn't in your `activity_main.xml` layout file.

Bearing in mind you're calling `setContentView(...)` in several places I'm guessing it's actually in the `browse_new.xml` layout file (or another layout file).

If that's the case then your problem is that you can only use `findViewById(...)` to find views in the current content view. Move whichever calls to `findViewById(...)` to the methods which change the content view. Example...

```
public void browseEvent(View V)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.browse_new);
    // Call findViewById(...) for any widgets in browse_new.xml here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting value of TextView without creating object i. e. via findViewById(int) method:

```
String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtextview)).getText().toString();
```